# The wrong number of daily active users, fabric

Tags: android, google-fabric

The last week fabric shows the wrong number of DAU, more precisely the DAU decreases with every day, yesterday it decreased thrice than actual number, is there any issue in fabric, or could it be that I did something wrong when I initialized it in my app. At the same time Firebase shows the right data. Did somebody faced such issue?

Comment: If you submit multiple requests within the application with different tokens, it is normal for them to be treated as different users. This process has been confronted in anonymous authentication on FireBase.